# How to get specific data from a natural language string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I am building an Rails 5 app (with a Nokogiri scraper) and I am trying to extract data from a string.

This is my string:

```
data = "3 rooms and kitchen, 43m²"
```

How can I get the following data out of that string?
Would be great if the result could end up in an array.

```
3
43
```

I think I need somehow use Regex but I have no idea how to.

Comment: Do you want to extract numbers from a string with that format or do you want to actually handle this with a natural language processor? will you always have that string format? (digits followed by non digits, followed by digits and then m2)

Comment: The format will (for now) always be the same. I need to extract the 3 (rooms) and 43 (square meters).

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". We need an example of what you tried, an explanation of why it didn't work and what you want as a result. Currently it looks like you didn't try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-scan) method:

```
data.scan(/\d+/)
#=> ["3", "43"]
```

If you want integers:

```
data.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)
#=> [3, 43]
```

You can extract values with `and` even if the sentence structure changes:

```
room_types = %w(rooms kitchen)
extracted_values = data.split('and').map do |sd|
  room_type = room_types.find{ |rt| sd.include?(rt) }
  { room_type => sd.scan(/\d+/).first.to_i }
end.reduce({}, :merge)

p extracted_values
#=> { "rooms" => 3, "kitchen" => 43 }
```